# jsii error when attempting to create a budget via AWS CDK in python

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I am attempting to create a budget via AWS CDK.

Here is the code, this is pieced together from referencing the official documentation and a TypeScript solution doing a similar thing.

```
email = 'yo@yo.yo'
value = 90.0
subscription = sns_sub.EmailSubscription(email)
topic = sns.Topic(self, id='notification_topic', display_name='budget notifications',
                          topic_name='budget_notifications')
topic.add_subscription(subscription)
budget_data_props = aws_budgets.CfnBudget.BudgetDataProperty(budget_type='COST', time_unit='MONTHLY', 
                                                             budget_name='CDK budget',
                                                             budget_limit=aws_budgets.CfnBudget.SpendProperty(amount=value, unit='USD'))
np = aws_budgets.CfnBudget.NotificationProperty(comparison_operator='GREATER_THAN',
                                                notification_type='FORECASTED', threshold=90.0,
                                                threshold_type='PERCENTAGE')
sub = aws_budgets.CfnBudget.SubscriberProperty(address=topic.topic_arn, subscription_type='SNS')
nws = aws_budgets.CfnBudget.NotificationWithSubscribersProperty(notification=np, subscribers=[sub])

budget_props = aws_budgets.CfnBudgetProps(budget=budget_data_props, notifications_with_subscribers=nws)
budget = aws_budgets.CfnBudget(self, 'cdk budget', budget=budget_props)
```

The error I get is:

Error:

> Value did not match any type in union: Wire struct type
> '@aws-cdk/aws-budgets.CfnBudgetProps' does not match expected
> '@aws-cdk/aws-budgets.CfnBudget.BudgetDataProperty', Expected object
> reference, got
> {"$jsii.struct":{"fqn":"@aws-cdk/aws-budgets.CfnBudgetProps","data":{"budget":{"$jsii.struct":{"fqn":"@aws-cdk/aws-budgets.CfnBudget.BudgetDataProperty","data":{"budgetType":"COST","timeUnit":"MONTHLY","budgetLimit":{"$jsii.struct":{"fqn":"@aws-cdk/aws-budgets.CfnBudget.SpendProperty","data":{"amount":10,"unit":"USD"}}},"budgetName":"CDK
> budget","costFilters":null,"costTypes":null,"plannedBudgetLimits":null,"timePeriod":null}}},"notificationsWithSubscribers":{"$jsii.struct":{"fqn":"@aws-cdk/aws-budgets.CfnBudget.NotificationWithSubscribersProperty","data":{"notification":{"$jsii.struct":{"fqn":"@aws-cdk/aws-budgets.CfnBudget.NotificationProperty","data":{"comparisonOperator":"GREATER_THAN","notificationType":"FORECASTED","threshold":90,"thresholdType":"PERCENTAGE"}}},"subscribers":[{"$jsii.struct":{"fqn":"@aws-cdk/aws-budgets.CfnBudget.SubscriberProperty","data":{"address":"${Token[TOKEN.56]}","subscriptionType":"SNS"}}}]}}}}}}

I'm using an IDE with type hinting, so I am at a loss for how this is having what appears to be a type mismatch.

Thank you for reading and for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using python and creating a Construct you have two options for passing props.  Using the Props object or using the parameters for the Props object as key/value pairs directly.  You are mixing those two methods. Since you are creating a Props object you should pass it directly

```
budget = aws_budgets.CfnBudget(self, 'cdk budget', budget_props)
```

You can also do it this way instead of creating a Props object

```
budget = aws_budgets.CfnBudget(
    self, 'cdk budget', 
    budget=budget_data_props, 
    notifications_with_subscribers=nws
)
```

Comment: Not that this isn't a potential solution, but I made these changes both ways and was left with the same error.

Is it possible this is only part of the problem?

Comment: It's possible it's a different error you are getting as they are really hard to interpret.  Given the error you posted in the question

"Value did not match any type in union: Wire struct type '@aws-cdk/aws-budgets.CfnBudgetProps' does not match expected '@aws-cdk/aws-budgets.CfnBudget.BudgetDataProperty',"

That's saying that on this line: 

budget = aws_budgets.CfnBudget(self, 'cdk budget', budget=budget_props)

that the "budget=" is expecting BudgetDataProperty but got CfnBudgetProps.  Switch to this and paste the error you get.

CfnBudget(self, 'cdk budget', budget_props)

Comment: If you would add to your solution that notifications_with_subscribers should be an array.

I'll give you the green check mark.